# Negative edge weight check in boost's dijkstra_shortest_paths

Tags: c++, boost, dijkstra

I am using the boost graph library to make a call to `dijkstra_shortest_paths`. However, I have something special setup in that the `weight_map` is actually a functor. Hence, everytime the boost library requires the weight of an edge, my functor is called, makes a complicated computation and delivers the result back to boost.

Unfortunately, in `dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp` the struct `dijkstra_bfs_visitor`'s method `examine_edge` has a `get` call to the weightmap, only to check if the returned value is negative. I am fully aware that I cannot use Dijkstra's algorithm with negative values and I am certain that my functor only returns positive values. However, this check causes my functor to be called twice for each edge. As it performs a complicated computation I'd like to avoid performing it twice (the results don't change between calls.. each edge gets the same wait during a `dijkstra_shortest_paths` run).

So far, I am manually checking the edge passed to the functor and in case of the duplicate call I am returning the previous remembered result. This clearly is more of a workaround than a solution.

I tried to pass my own visitor that overwrites `examine_edge`, however, the original method defined by boost's `dijkstra_bfs_visitor` is still applied.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to handle this situation and somehow avoid the negate edge weight check?

Comment: if it's expensive, caching this edge weight calculation seems like a good idea anyways. other than that...maybe you can provide a combine functor that always returns false?

Comment: I do cache it already, of course. I just don't like the functor being called twice for no reason. The combine functor should return a distance value, so what do you mean with returning false?

Comment: Can you derive from the `struct DijkstraVisitorConcept` and overload your own `void constraints()` function, where you can remove the `examine_edge()` check altogether.

Comment: @Aditya Kumar: Sounds like an answer to me -- you should post that in the answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, even supplying you own visitor the test of negativity will be performed.

```
  void examine_edge(Edge e, Graph& g) {
    if (m_compare(get(m_weight, e), m_zero))
        boost::throw_exception(negative_edge());
    m_vis.examine_edge(e, g);
  }
```

But anyway the weight_map is supposed to be called multiple time (see boost [doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html)):

```
 for each vertex v in Adj[u]
  if (w(u,v) + d[u] < d[v])
    d[v] := w(u,v) + d[u]
```

Just call djikstra with a precomputed weight map, every edge weight will have to be computed anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not true in my case. First: the doc does not say, that it calls w(u,v) twice. This is just pseudo-code and boost may as well re-use the result. Second, I cannot precompute, because my visitor throws an exception on reaching a target vertex, so I wouldn't know what to precompute (and obviously, don't want to compute it all).

Comment: Well the way it is documented suggest that you shouldn't rely on the fact that it is called only once. Then memoization is a possible choice. Or inherit from `DijkstraVisitorConcept` as suggest by Aditya Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use lazy computation to ensure that each expensive computation is carried out at most once. The most straightforward way to implement this would be give your `Edge` class a `getWeight()` lazy getter, I'm not familiar with the library you're using so I'm not sure how you'd integrate that with the functor.